# Importing SockJS into Lit project fails

Tags: javascript, sockjs, lit

I am building a web component using Lit that utilizes sockjs-client, but I'm encountering issues when attempting to import the library.

When using import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';, I receive the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js' does not provide an export named 'default'."

When trying import { SockJS } from 'sockjs-client';, I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js' does not provide an export named 'SockJS'."

Importing using import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client'; results in the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined."

The only working solution so far is importing from a CDN, but I would prefer not to depend on a CDN. Can anyone provide advice?

Comment: This depends on how you're bundling your app. It doesn't look like `sockjs-client` provides ESM code. Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-commonjs could help.

Comment: Did you find a way how to handle it?